# Swagger ignores Schema properties for referenced schemas

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am using Swagger Core 2.0.2 for Java to generate an OpenAPI documentation. Among others, I have the following class `SomeDTO`:

```
@Schema(name = "SomeDTO", description = "some description")
public class SomeDTO {
  @Schema(description = "description of name")
  private String name;
  @Schema(required = true, description = "description of OtherDTO")
  private OtherDTO otherDTO;
}
```

`OtherDTO` is described as follows:

```
public class OtherDTO {
  @Schema(required = true)
  private String someField;
  private String someOtherField;
}
```

My problem is that neither the `description` nor the `required` field above the `otherDTO` field has any effect.

The resulting `openapi.json` looks like this:

```
    "components": {
      "schemas": {
        "SomeDTO" : {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type" : "string"
            }
            "otherDTO" : {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/OtherDTO"
            }
          },
          "description": "some description"
        },
        "OtherDTO": {
          "required": ["someField"],
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "somefield": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "someOtherField": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I was expecting the `SomeDTO` schema to have a `required` array containing `OtherDTO`, which it does not. The description is also lost.

I have tried numerous combinations of Schema settings, to no avail. I would highly appreciate any help to understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution to part of my problem.

The problem is caused by the fact that when using a `$ref` element, [sibling elements are ignored.](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/#sibling) So elements (`description`, `name` etc.) related to the referenced element need to be specified as a `@Schema` in the referenced object itself (`OtherDTO` in the example above). Specifying these elements in the parent object (e.g. `SomeDTO`) will leave them ignored.

However, the schema elements in the referenced element do not seem to propagate up to the parent object. So, to make `otherDTO` a required field in `SomeDTO`, I need to add `requiredProperties = { "OtherDTO" })` to `SomeDTO`'s schema.

Here is the updated code:

`SomeDTO`

```
@Schema(name = "SomeDTO", description = "some description",
requiredProperties = { "OtherDTO" })
public class SomeDTO {
  @Schema(description = "description of name")
  private String name;
  private OtherDTO otherDTO;
}
```

`OtherDTO`

```
@Schema(name = "OtherDTO", description = "Description of OtherDTO")
public class OtherDTO {
  @Schema(required = true)
  private String someField;
  private String someOtherField;
}
```

However, it does not solve my problem completely, as I still can't figure out how to set the `description` of `otherDTO` in `SomeDTO`. But it gets me a step closer.